# Multiplo INSERT Models Laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema e me deparei com a seguinte situação:

Preciso inserir os dados primeiro na tabela 'pessoa', recuperar o último 'id_pessoa' e logo depois inserir os dados na tabela 'fornecedor' tudo no método **store**, observem abaixo o que eu tenho até agora;

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    //capturar todos os dados digitados
    $dadosPessoa = $request->all ();

    //realizar insert via Eloquent e retornar o id_pessoa
    $id_pessoa = Pessoa::create ( $dadosPessoa )->id_pessoa;

    //id_pessoa na tabela pessoa é id_pessoa na tabela fornecedor 
    $input ['id_pessoa'] = $id_pessoa;

    Fornecedor::create ($input);
}
```

Sei que falta algo mas não sei ao certo o que, quando executo o código a tabela **pessoa** recebe os dados, mas a tabela **fornecedor**, não recebe nada e retorna o seguinte erro:

> SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 ERRO: valor nulo na coluna
>   "inscricao_estadual" viola a restrição não-nula DETAIL: Registro que
>   falhou contém (13, 36, null). (SQL: insert into "fornecedor"
>   ("id_pessoa") values (36) returning "id_fornecedor")

Alguém tem uma sugestão?

Comment: Você não está passando nada ao Eloquent para que ele saiba o que deve ter na tabela de Fornecedor. Assim como fez o _$request->all()_ e passou para o _Pessoa::create..._ tem de fazer para o fornecedor. Agora, sobre o id do fornecedor, não entendi o que quer na verdade... cada fornecedor pertence a uma pessoa? Como está seu model? Poste seu model aqui parar que possa te ajudar melhor. Se for isso, e se tiver feito as ligações no model, ficará bem fácil! Aguardo detalhes. Abs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agradeço a todos que tentaram me ajudar nessa questão, consegui resolver da seguinte forma:

```
   public function store(Request $request) {

        //captura dados Model Pessoa
        $dadosPessoa = $request->except('inscricao_estadual');

        //captura dados Model Fornecedor
        $inscricao_estadual = $request->input('inscricao_estadual');

       //realizar insert via Eloquent e retornar o último id_pessoa
       $id_pessoa = Pessoa::create($dadosPessoa)->id_pessoa;    

       //realizar insert via Eloquent e retornar o último id_pessoa
       $fornecedor = Fornecedor::create(['id_pessoa' => $id_pessoa, 'inscricao_estadual' => $inscricao_estadual]);      

       flash()->success('Fornecedor adicionado com sucesso');
       return redirect()->action('FornecedorController@index');

}
```

Acima está o meu método completo para quem precisar de ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

Isso é por causa da coluna não poder ser nula, ou seja, na tabela do fornecedor de ve estar definida na sua base de dados como `not null`, ou você muda o default para essa coluna aceitar valores nulos. Se tiver criado as tabelas em php (laravel) pode acrescentar:

```
Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
...
   $table->string('inscricao_estadual')->nullable();
...
}
```

Ou você pode fazer isso manualmente diratamente na sua base de dados. Pỗr `NULL`

E você dentro do array input só tem o `id_pessoa` talvez o que quer seja isto:

```
$dadosPessoa = $request->except('_token'); // todos menos o _token
$id_pessoa = Pessoa::create ( $dadosPessoa )->id_pessoa;
$input['id_pessoa'] = $id_pessoa;
$input['inscricao_estadual'] = $dadosPessoa['inscricao_estadual'];
Fornecedor::create ($dadosPessoa);
```

Comment: Eu preciso dos dados, eles não podem ser nulos.

Comment: Então insira algum dado nessa coluna, pelo código que mostrou não está a inserir nada na coluna `inscricao_estadual`, e isso é interpretado como null, e na sua tabela essa coluna não pode ser null

Comment: Quando executo dd($dadosPessoa = $request->all ()); recebo os dados vindos do formulário, inclusive inscricao_estadual, como fazer para inserir apenas esse campo na tabela fornecedor?

Comment: E tem a certeza não está vazio? E que o index desse valor no array `$input` está bem escrito (`inscricao_estadual`) e não é vazio?

Comment: Sim, observe o retorno:
array:10 [▼
  "_token" => "WrnRuydOrlvIZDZZm3Mg0wCJadtjI7XTAB48NYJr"
  "nome" => "teste"
  "documento" => "00000"
  "inscricao_estadual" => "0000000"
  "id_uf" => "8"
  "id_cidade" => "1"
  "cep" => "000000000"
  "endereco" => "000000"
  "bairro" => "00000000"
  "numero" => "0000000"
]

Comment: Todos os dados são retornados

Comment: Você só está a atribuir um valor e um index ao array `$input`. Não definiu mais nada dentro dele

Comment: Alguma sugestão de como fazer?

Comment: Ainda recebo o mesmo erro informando que inscricao_estadual esta NULL

Comment: No seu model `fornecedor`, tem `inscricao_estadual` no array `$fillable`

Comment: @Miguel eu já especifiquei isso na minha resposta

Comment: Desculpe, mas eu não estou a controlar a sua resposta... Estou a controlar  a minha com o objetivo de ajudar o colega. É isso que queremos certo

Comment: Continuo a dizer que pelo código que postou o array `$input` não tem mais nada para além do `id_pessoa`

Comment: Justamente @Miguel, de fato não tem, como posso capturar esse campo "inscricao_estadual"?

Answer (score 1):

Amigo. De acordo com o erro apresentado o campo inscricao_estadual de sua tabela **fornecedor** não pode ser nulo e sua variável `$input` parece não conter esse campo.
Recomendo você utilizar o `DB::transaction(function(){});` para controle de querys em mais de uma tabela. Isso porque se hover algum erro o laravel automaticamente executara o Rolback das informações, impedindo que os dados fiquem inconsistente no seu banco de dados. Ex:

```
  public function store(Request $request) {

      \DB::transaction(function() use($request) {

       $dadosPessoa = $request->all();

       $pessoa = Pessoa::create($dadosPessoa);

       $input['id_pessoa'] = $pessoa->id_pessoa;

       Fornecedor::create($input);

      });
  }
```

Se no banco de dados o campo inscricao_estadual está configurada para not null você não conseguirá fazer o insert se a `$input['inscricao_estadual'] = '';` Nesse caso. Esse campo deve ser validado para obrigatório.
Para fazer a validação e garantir que o campo não será enviado vazio.

você tem duas opções:

utilizar o `validate()`
ou request, segue o exemplo que como criar o request para validação:

para criar um request abra seu terminal e na raiz do projeto

```
php artisan make:request FornecedorRequest
```

Note que será criada uma classe request em `app\Http\Requests`

```
public function authorize()
{
      return true;
}


public function rules()
{
    $rules = [
        'inscricao_estadual' => 'required',
        'id_pessoa' => 'required'
    ];
    return $rules;
}
```

O parametro de seu metodo store deve ser alterado para

```
public function store(FornecedorRequest $request)
```

e nessa classe que contém o método store deve conter a inclusão dessa request

```
use app\Http\Requests\FornecedorRequest
```

Verifique se no seu model Fornecedor tem o indice iscricao_estadual no `$fillable`

```
protected $fillable = [
        'inscricao_estadual',
        'id_pessoa'
    ];
```

se não estiver especificado o model irá ignorar esse campo no insert.

Comment: Foi uma boa idéia, mas realmente preciso que o campo inscricao_estadual, seja inserido na tabela fornecedor, é justamente o que não consegui fazer ainda.

Comment: Mas pelo seu código essa informação não está sendo passada. Por isso o motivo do erro

Comment: Como eu poderia usar a variável $input para passar o campo inscricao_estadual?

Comment: vou colocar na resposta

Comment: @geekcom editei minha resposta

Comment: Não havia validado, foi muito útil sua resposta, estou usando validator, mas ainda não consigo fazer o insert.